# Timezone: Why would someone want to set their system timezone as different from the real one?

Tags: linux, timezone

For example, a computer in USA with a system timezone of Arctic/Longyearbyen...

What benefits does it have, if any? Also, what are the potential disadvantages of doing so?

Answer (score 3):

There's always UTC (as it "should be"), which doesn't have daylight savings time. (And probably, you "should" be used to just counting seconds since the epoch so you don't get leap days and leap seconds either, but it's probably pretty hard for most humans to tell a timestamp from yesterday from one from two months ago.)

Once you have local time… a person in France renting a virtual server in the US Midwest would probably still like French-time timestamps instead of being eight hours off (and sometimes more or less, depending on DST).

So in an attempt to bring this into a coherent answer: at the very latest when you work with several systems, you really want them to all have the same time zone, because converting is a hassle that gets in the way. (From correlating log file entries to looking at if that config file needs to be copied over, yes, it's only a small thing, but it's a constant drain on your attention.)
That would probably either be "your local timezone" if such a thing exists, or UTC. Maybe there are use cases for being near the date line TZ-wise, so that you're always "earlier/later than anywhere else on the planet" (like they do with international submission deadlines in academia), but I can't see much benefit in randomly picking, say Europe/Büsingen or Arctic/Longyearbyen.